# ScrollView seems to set a top margin for its child

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have an issue with `ScrollView` which seems to add a top margin for its child. I have a `LinearLayout` above it, which sets Top margin in order for the layout to be below other elements (its parent is `FrameLayout`), then `ScrollView` is inserted into the `LinearLayout`, and a finally a child is attached to `ScrollView`.

The following image shows empty space that appears between "border" and order details (TextView):
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AgoX.png)

**Java Code:**

```
// Inner layout to accommodate ScrollView
    LinearLayout inner_layout = new LinearLayout(app.getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams inner_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 440);
    inner_params.setMargins(0, 135, 0, 0);
    inner_layout.setLayoutParams(inner_params);

    // ScrollView for details of the order (in case everything doesn't fit in the body)
    ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(app.getApplicationContext());
    params_in = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    scrollView.setLayoutParams(params_in);
    scrollView.setFillViewport(false);

    TextView body_text = new TextView(app.getApplicationContext());
    params_in = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params_in.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 10);
    body_text.setLayoutParams(params_in);
    body_text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTextSecondary, null));
```

It's almost as if top margin of 135 is also used for `ScrollView`'s child.

If someone could help understand what I'm doing wrong I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Please share XML code.

Comment: XML code is not used for this.

Comment: Why don't you use XML? Well I believe margin Top is assigned to both LinearLayouts the parent one for the whole order window and for the one which has children inside ScrollView.

Comment: I don't use XML for this case specifically because the number of these "orders" created depends on the content held in the database. I decided to re-write this function to LinearLayout as it doesn't seem to cause issues such as this.